# Data in one cell in excel wants to be divided in multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL|

I have the above data. I want to create a formula by which all the data will get divided into different cells using | as delimiter

Answer (score 2):

`FILTERXML()` will give you desired result.

```
 =FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")
```

[image]

To get results in horizontal alignment use `TRANSPOSE()`

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]

More about `FILTERXML()` is here by JvdV [Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747)

Answer (score 2):

You can try Text to Column [image]

1. "Data" Tab
2. "Text to Columns"
3. "Delimited" Option
4. Type the bar "|" in the "Other" option box